# A good practise book suggestion

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials

I am a beginner in Special Functions. So I am looking for **a Good Practise/Application  Book**  about the  properties of Hypergoemetric Function  and its relations with orthogonal polynomials. I want to learn finding
derivative, contiguous relations, integral representation, differential equalities and transformations practisely. You can suggest a thesis or article
, pdf, too. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For various properties of  Hypergoemetric Function, you can try the following references:

$(1)~~$ "Special functions and their applications" by N. N. Lebedev
$~~~~~~~~~$ It is a great reference for special functions with many physics - engineering applications. Also it is one of the very few books that give guidance and insight in the more difficult elements of that derivation.

$(2)~~$ "Textbook of Ordinary Differential Equations" by C. R. Mondal
$~~~~~~~~~$ It contains a detailed discussion (with lot of examples) on some well-known special functions. Many of the standard concepts and methods which are useful in the study of special functions are discussed. The properties of special functions are derived from their differential equations and boundary conditions.

$(3)~~$ "Special functions for scientists and engineers" by W. W. Bell
$~~~~~~~~~$ It is a good book of special functions for people who are just starting to study them, there are several examples of their properties that are useful, the only thing that lacks the book is that it does not contain examples of where to occupy the special functions

Also you can find some other references from these links:

[Reference Book on Special Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759377/reference-book-on-special-functions)
[Book recommendation on special functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639809/book-recommendation-on-special-functions)
[Good reference for Special functions/no elementary functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127201/good-reference-for-special-functions-no-elementary-functions)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions:) i will look at all.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own it, but [Special Functions: A Graduate Text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052119797X) might be worth looking into.