# Beginners Book for Fresnel Integrals

Tags: calculus

I am a Math major but I haven't studied Fresnel integrals. Now I encounter these integrals during my Master's research. Please can you suggest to me any book to start learning Fresnel integrals. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with complex function theory ? It is in this context that it is better to "start".

Comment: Dealing only with real Fresnel integrals, the wikipedia article mentions the connection with **clothoid** curve which is an "oddity": its arcs are used as a connecting devices between rails of two different shapes : linear and circular arcs preserving curvature smoothness.

Comment: yes, I am good at complex analysis, can you please suggest to me any book for a detailed discussion of Fresnel integrals.

Comment: Any suggestions for a  book explaining Gaussian integrals are also welcome.

Comment: Therefore, what you need is a book/site devoted to **special functions** in general like the ones that are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/759377). I don't know if there exists a book completely devoted to Fresnel's integrals. Situating them with respect to other special functions (oscillary behavior, etc.) is probably  the best you have to do.